# Using DAX to Count or Calulate Values

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to create a measure in Power BI and I'm having some trouble.

I have a table called 'clients' which as a column called 'status' that has multiplies values in it.

I want to create a formula that counts the number of how many times the value  'Kept' shows up in that column.

```
Total = COUNT('client'[status])
```

I'm just not sure where to go from here. I don't know if COUNT or SUM would be the correct function. I know this is a simple solution but I can't figure this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CALCULATE` function allows you to add simple filters using additional arguments.

```
CALCULATE(
    COUNT('client'[status]),
    'client'[status] = "Kept"
)
```

Comment: What would I do if I wanted to calculate more than one value? I tried 

The CALCULATE function allows you to add simple filters using additional arguments.

CALCULATE(
    COUNT('client'[status]),
    'client'[status] = "Kept", "ABC"
)

Comment: If you want either of those to work, then you can change `'client'[status] = "Kept"` to `'client'[status] IN {"Kept","ABC"}`.